# MIDIDestinationCreate and UIBackgroundmodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, coremidi

I have written an app which uses midi for playing audio.  The app uses MIDIDestinationCreate and enables UIBackgroundmodes as suggested by Apple in the iOS6 release notes.

The App review team have rejected the app because they say that it does not play any sound when put into background mode.  They suggested that I change the plist accordingly and uncheck audio/background mode.  This of course causes the app to crash when playing the midi and is also mentioned in the question here as well as the iOS6 release notes:

[CoreMIDI/PGMidi Virtual midi error in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548856/coremidi-pgmidi-virtual-midi-error-in-ios6)

Ideally, I don't want it to play music when in the background. When the user puts the app in the background, they've finished.

I replied to the app review team referring them to the iOS6 release notes for MIDIDestinationCreate.  This made no difference - they just maintain that audio needs to play while that user has dismissed the app - perhaps like iTunes I guess.

They suggested submitting a DST for an alternative solution- which I have done but there's no reply.

Are there other solutions for playing midi or perhaps ways of appeasing the app review team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer support team replied and there was no issue with the method of implementation.

It seems like the reviewer made a mistake. I lodged an appeal and the App was approved.